# Get Table selection and File in same form POST

Tags: python, html, django, file-upload, django-tables2

I have a django template that houses a django_table2 table, and also accepts a file:

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block title %}{{user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} Portal{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <input type=button value="Back" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
    <h4>Currently registered vehicles:</h4>
    <div class='vehlist'>
        <form action="/loadlocndb/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% render_table veh_list %}


            <h4> Location database .csv file</h4>
            <input type="file" name="myfile"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Currently the only thing passed back in `POST` is the selected table checkboxes. How do I also pass back the file as well.

views.py

```
@login_required   
def locndb(request):
    # This is the basic user landing Page
    veh_list =VehicleTable(Vehicle.objects.filter(company__user=request.user))
    form = LocnDBForm()
    RequestConfig(request).configure(veh_list)
    return render(request, 'portal/locndb.html', {"veh_list": veh_list, "form": form})

@login_required   
def loadlocndb(request):


    if request.method == "POST":
        pks = request.POST.getlist("update")
        print pks
        selected_objects = Vehicle.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)

        vlist = []
        for i in selected_objects:
            vlist.append(i)

        return render(request, 'portal/loadlocndb.html',{"vlist":vlist})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from portal.models import UserProfile, Vehicle

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('milkco', 'compName')

class LocnDBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ('vehid','locndb',)
```

vehicle model

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehid = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    company = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default = 1)
    #depot = models.ForeignKey(Depot, default = 1)
    locndb = models.FileField(upload_to="optiload/", default= "setting.MEDIA_ROOT/locndb/LocnDB.csv")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "vehicle"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.vehid
```

Even better is how would stop the user from processing without selecting at least one entry in the table and also a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your `loadlocndb` view:

```
@login_required   
def loadlocndb(request):


if request.method == "POST":
    pks = request.POST.getlist("update")

    myfile = request.FILES['form_field_name'].file
    print pks, myfile

    selected_objects = Vehicle.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)

    vlist = []
    for i in selected_objects:
        vlist.append(i)

    return render(request, 'portal/loadlocndb.html',{"vlist":vlist})
```

I haven't tested it, but this: `request.FILES['form_field_name'].file`
will get the file from your form. Just replace your file form field name with `'form_field_name'`.

Can you please put your code from your form.py?

And in your template, you should replace `<form action="/loadlocndb/" method="POST">` with `<form action="/loadlocndb/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads): Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: I've added the forms.py and model class

Comment: so in your case, you can get the file like request.FILES['locndb'].file ,

Comment: and change <input type="file" name="myfile"> to <input type="file" name="locndb">, Have you tried any of the changes?

Comment: I get a `MultiValueDictKeyError: "'locndb'"` error when trying to upload the file.

Comment: i guess it is getting confused about locndb field. try to replace <input type="file" name="locndb"> with {{ form.locndb }}